# Crystal equivalent to SQL NOT IN statement

Tags: sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

In a crystal sub report

I've got a table called  `individuals`, another table called `attribute`.

An individual can have several attributes.

If they have a particular attribute I want to exclude them from my results.

IN SQL I'd use a subquery with: `SELECT individual_ref WHERE NOT In (SELECT individual_ref from attribute where etc)`

> So if I can't have a Subquery in crystal how can I produce this sort of exclusion result?

I thought of using a stored procedure but I can't pass parameters to it in a sub report.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.individual_ref
    FROM individuals i
        LEFT JOIN attribute a
            ON i.individual_ref = a.individual_ref
                and a.attribute = @AttributeToExclude
    WHERE a.individual_ref IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks but in Crystal I can't add and statements to the join condition.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this solution frequently. It's not elegant, but it works:

1. In your subreport, create a formula called something like `HasBadAttribute_Num`:

   ```
   if {a.id} in ["badAttr1", "badAttr2", "badAttr3"] then 1 else 0
   ```
2. Create a grouping level for individual.
3. Add a **Group Selection Formula** to that group:

   ```
   Sum({@HasBadAttribute_Num}, {a.individual_ref})
   ```